# Mysqli multi_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two very similar scripts – one scheduled script, the other triggered by loading a PHP page – that download and parse email, then insert the various information I need into 3 tables. A simplified version of the query I had been using is:

```
INSERT INTO mailids () VALUES ();  
SET @mysql_mid = LAST_INSERT_ID();  
INSERT INTO mail (  
    mail_mid,   
    mail_owner_id,   
    mail_recipient,   
    mail_sender,   
    mail_subject,   
    mail_sent_date   
) VALUES (  
    @mysql_mid,   
    '$userId',   
    '$recipient',   
    '$sender',   
    '$subject',  
    FROM_UNIXTIME('$sentDate')  
);  
SET @mysql_mail_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();  
INSERT INTO mail_body (  
    mail_id,  
    mail_body  
) VALUES (  
    @mysql_mail_id,  
    '$body'  
);  
UPDATE mailids SET mid_rec_ids = @mysql_mail_id WHERE mid_id = @mysql_mid;
```

This worked just fine unless both scripts run at the same time, in which case both insert the email into the database, resulting in a duplicate entry.

What I was hoping to do was add a SELECT statement to the beginning of my multi_query followed by an IF statement (which I have no experience with) that would only execute the above query if the email didn't already exist. In other words:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS mail_count FROM mail WHERE mail_owner_id = '$user_id AND mail_recipient = '$recipient' AND mail_sender = '$sender' AND mail_subject = '$subject' AND mail_sent_date = '$sent_date';

IF mail_count < 1  
THEN   
    (INSERT ABOVE QUERY HERE)  
END IF
```

Nothing I have tried has worked. I've tried setting a variable (@mail_count), using WHERE NOT EXISTS (which, for some reason, inserts a number of records equal to all records with my user_id) and about 100 other things I don't remember offhand. I considered going with PDO, but the rest of the project is mysqli and I am afraid of the learning curve of PDO in this project timeline.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What about [INSERT IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)? Of course, you must use an index on the appropriate fields to define duplication criteria!

Comment: If I understand correctly, INSERT IGNORE only compares unique keys. I thought about concatenating the fields into one and making it a unique field. Perhaps that is what I should do?

Comment: Yes, but this whole logic seems overcomplicated. Why do you allow two instances of the same procedure to run with the same arguments? You should use locking on the app layer or transactions on the db layer.

Comment: One instance is to keep data reasonably up-to-date without the user having to wait for emails to download and parse. The other is for occasions when a user doesn't want to wait until the automated task is queued again.

Comment: If both play the same routine (i.e. executing the same PHP functions/methods) and your application logic requires that only one instance is running at a time (as it seems), then you must employ some ind of locking to ensure a second instance would wait for the first to finish. E.g. there is [PHP flock](http://php.net/flock).

Comment: You really don't want to do this, `multi_query` is a landmine that will explode on you eventually. For one, it's very annoying to secure from SQL injection. Secondly, you have zero ability to discern which query failed if something malfunctions. Third, it's not immune to race conditions or other bugs related to timing. Use a transaction plus regular statements using placeholder values. That will give you full control over the operation of this query, plus will ensure things are added atomically and consistently.

Comment: PDO is also not that hard to learn since it's about 80% the same in principle as `mysqli` with ever so slightly different names for functions.

Comment: You need to have a UNIQUE key on whatever fields define "duplicate". Then you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY to do whatever you want to do in that situation, possibly as simple as ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE.